# fs/promises API in TypeScript is not compiling correctly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node.js-fs

I was recently working with TypeScript and the fs/promises API and got this error when the TypeScript code was compiled and run. I got this error saying:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'
```

When I looked at the compiled code, this is what I found...

```
var promises_1 = require("fs/promises");
```

Which started working by changing it to

```
var promises_1 = require("fs").promises;
```

This is my **TypeScript file** import:

```
import { readFile, writeFile, appendFile } from "fs/promises";
```

My **package.json** file:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cheerio": "^0.22.22",
    "@types/got": "^9.6.11",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "got": "^11.8.0"
  }
```

And my **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Node.js version: **12.18.0**

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which Node.js version do you use? If I understand correctly, `fs/promises` module is available starting from v12, in v10 and earlier it's only an object `promises` under module `fs`.

Comment: @Cerberus thanks for the reply I am using node version v12.18.4

Comment: I have node v12.14.1 and have the same issue !!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The error was due to unsupported Node version 12.x which doesn't support this require statement...

```
var promises_1 = require("fs/promises");
```

but this works

```
var promises_1 = require("fs").promises;
```

This can be solved by updating the Node to the latest.

Comment: I use `import {promises as fsp} from "fs"`

Comment: Or you can do `const { promises: fs } = require("fs")`

Answer (score 62):

The solution I like best:

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

async function main() {
  await fs.writeFile('test.txt', 'hello');
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @Javarome for the inspiration in a comment

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me in node v12.18.1 was:

```
import { promises } from "fs";
const { readFile, writeFile } = promises;
```

I could use both methods within nestJS/express context.

Answer (score 1):

In the used version of Node.js, there's no dedicated module `fs/promises` yet, according to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/v12.18.4/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api). It should be possible, however, to upgrade Node.js to the latest 12.x, so that the module will be accessible.

Comment: Documentation states that the latest 12.x is 12.19 - https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/fs.html

Answer (score 0):

For importing specific methods you can use - example for:
*copyFile, rename*:

```
import { copyFile, rename } from 'node:fs/promises';
```