# when running pm2 start index.js it show that it is online and when i am doing pm2 list it show error occured and below is the error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, server, project

```
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/index-out.log last 15 lines:
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/index-error.log last 15 lines:
0|index    | Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'
0|index    | Require stack:
0|index    | - /home/ubuntu/codeial_project/node_modules/rotating-file-stream/dist/cjs/index.js
0|index    | - /home/ubuntu/codeial_project/config/environment.js
0|index    | - /home/ubuntu/codeial_project/index.js
0|index    |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
0|index    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
0|index    |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
0|index    |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
0|index    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/codeial_project/node_modules/rotating-file-stream/dist/cjs/index.js:8:20)
0|index    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
0|index    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
0|index    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
0|index    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
0|index    |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
```

I have tried different `pm2` versions and and even tried to uninstall and then install `fs` and `rfs` packages but getting same error

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725249/fs-promises-api-in-typescript-not-compiling-in-javascript-correctly